# Strange bug involving dynamic addition of LinearLayout view to LinearLayout container

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-edittext

I got this app (that is as good as done btw), where I need to add a LinearLayout view to a LinearLayout container dynamically. The way it works is that the user writes something in an EditText and presses the 'return' key on the keyboard. When the return key event is detected, a LinearLayout with another EditText view in it is added directly under the one that the user just edited, and the focus is switched to the EditText view inside the LineaLayout that was just added. This creates a vertical list of LinearLayouts with EditText views inside (see video below for illustration). It all works fine on the two testing devices I have and also on the five different devices of my small alpha testing group and I cannot seem to recreate the bug in the emulator. However when testing on my boss' devices (he is in another country, so I can't just show him my devices), the new EditText view never appears and the text written in the current EditText view disappears in a very buggy way (again see video below).

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjLSYkBVnJ0&feature=youtu.be) is a video of the bug. The intended behaviour is to insert another LinearLayout with the two EditText view inside it (and displaying a '2' instead of a '1'), however as you can see a new LinearLayout does not appear and the text is deleted from the current EditText view. I can record a video of the intended behaviour as well if needed.

The code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Create a listener for the item fields
    TextView.OnEditorActionListener itemListener = new OnItemEditorListener();
    nextItem.setOnEditorActionListener(itemListener);
    nextItem.addTextChangedListener(new ListTextWatcher());
}

private LinearLayout addLine(int i, String text){
    LinearLayout line = createline(R.layout.list_item_add);
    EditText listTextView = (EditText) line.getChildAt(1); 
    if(!text.equals(""))
        listTextView.setText(text);
    itemContainer.addView(line);
    int index = i + 1;
    ((EditText) line.getChildAt(0)).setText(index + ".");
    listTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnItemEditorListener());
    listTextView.addTextChangedListener(new ListTextWatcher());
    return line;
}

private class OnItemEditorListener implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        //Check if the current action is a keyDown event on the return button of the keyboard
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            final EditText currentView = (EditText) view;
            //if there is no text in the current field, do nothing
            if(currentView.getText().toString().equals(""))
                return true;
            int childCount = itemContainer.getChildCount();
            LinearLayout newLine = null;
            //iterate through all existing item lines 
            for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++){
                LinearLayout currentLine = (LinearLayout) itemContainer.getChildAt(i);
                //Check if the current iteration is looking at the line that had focus when return was pressed
                if(currentView.equals(currentLine.getChildAt(1))){
                    //check if the current line is the last item, and if so add a new line
                    if(i == childCount - 1)
                        newLine = addLine(i + 1, "");
                    //if current line is not the last line, give focus to the next line
                    else
                        newLine = (LinearLayout) itemContainer.getChildAt(i + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            nextItem = (EditText) newLine.getChildAt(1);
            nextItem.requestFocus();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the LinearLayout that gets added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/item_index"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.15"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_left_white_background"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:text="@string/one_dot"
    android:textColor="@color/ts1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.85"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corners_right_white_background"
    android:hint="@string/new_item"
    android:lines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is very frustrating, since I cannot to anything about this bug so long as I am unable to recreate it. As mentioned none of the devices I have access to behaves this way and I cannot get the emulator to do it either.

The two devices that are showing the bug:

1. Sony Ericsson Xperia PLAY (Android 2.3.3)
2. Samsung Nexus S (Android 4.1.2)

Devices where the app is working as intended:

1. HTC One S (Android 4.1.1)
2. Samsung I9000 Galaxy S (Android 2.3.5)
3. Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II (Android 2.3.4)
4. HTC One X (Android 4.0)
5. Google Nexus 4 (Android 4.2, I think)
6. AVDs set up as the two devices showing the bug

I am looking for some advice as to find what is causing this bug or just some advice as to recreating the bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well judging by the video the problem probably occurs in this line returning false on those devices.

```
 if(actionId == EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
```

Try doing this

```
 if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
```

Or this

```
 if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
```

My theory is that those devices handle keyboard events differently somehow?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. You are probably right (uploading changes right now to test). It never occurred to me that the 'text disappearing' is just the return key making a new line in the EditText view, I thought it was some sort of weird bug.

Comment: Damn, didn't work. Thought for sure that was it. I think however you are right that the problem is catching the key event correctly.